# How to set font to particular div in mPDF?

Tags: codeigniter, mpdf

1. How to set font to particular div in m-PDF ?

   I am using like this. but it's not working

   ```
      div { font-size: 14pt; font-family: dejavuserif;}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can put style as Inline like this

```
$html = "<div style='font-size: 14pt; font-family: dejavuserif;'>Text Here</div>";
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

**or**

**create a css file with name customeStyle.css.**
**add this style into customeStyle.css**

```
div { font-size: 14pt; font-family: dejavuserif;}
```

and code is

```
$stylesheet = file_get_contents('customeStyle.css');
$html = "<div>Text Here</div>";
$mpdf = new mPDF('utf-8', 'A4-L');
$mpdf->WriteHTML($stylesheet, 1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```